# multiple file_exists function in one if statement overwrite each other

Tags: php, file, if-statement, overriding

I am creating a word to image converter and for multy image words, I need to write a bit more complex `if` statements.

My first `if` statement works well for 2 image word(word = image + image):

```
$words = array("car", "bike",...)

foreach ($words as $x => $word) {

    $jpg = "Pictures/".$words[$x] . ".jpg";
    $jpg1 = "Pictures/".$word."/".$word. "1.jpg";
    $jpg2 = "Pictures/".$word."/".$word. "2.jpg";
    $jpg3 = "Pictures/".$word."/".$word. "3.jpg";

    if (file_exists($jpg1) && file_exists($jpg2)) {
        print '<div class="result1"><div id="result1" style="background-image:url('.$jpg1.')"></div>
        <div id="result2" style="background-image:url('.$jpg2.')"></div>
        <a id="word'. $x .'">'. $words[$x] .'</a></div>';
    }
```

This `if` spatement says that if the file in directory `jpg1 and jpg2` exists, print this...So if it locates just the two files in those directories it will work.

However, when I try adding a 3rd `file_exists` function to an `else if` statement like this:

```
else if (file_exists($jpg1) && file_exists($jpg2) && file_exists($jpg3)) {
    print '<div class="result2"><div id="result3" style="background-image:url('.$jpg1.')"></div>
    <div id="result4" style="background-image:url('.$jpg2.')"></div>
    <div id="result5" style="background-image:url('.$jpg3.')"></div>
    <a id="word'. $x .'">'. $words[$x] .'</a></div>';
}
```

The first `if` statement overrides the second one, even though the second one is correct. and the first one isn't.

I wanted to ask if everything is correct with my syntax? Or if I can even use multiple `file_exists` functions like this.

Or any other reason why this might not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because PHP checks each `if/elseif/else` condition __in turn__ until it finds the first one that matches as true... as your first match succeeds, the second will never be tested

Comment: Reverse the order of your `if` and `elseif` checks

Comment: Yeah I thought so but didnt know how to go about repairing it, my answer below solved it, but will see how it works when there are other `if` statements